# SafeAreaView top not showing background color in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native app where I want to show the top part of device with brand color (blue in this case) but instead it shows transparent/grey and only the main body shows blue color, how can I make it so it also shows top colored blue instead of grey?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrZ80.jpg

in my App.js

```
return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'rgb(3,91,150)', paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 0 : 0 }}>
        <NavigationContainer>
            <ROOTSTACK1></ROOTSTACK1>
        </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaView>
    );
```

How can I make it so the top part is colored instead of grey color in image.

Answer (score 0):

The area you are talking is out of safe area. It is status bar. Please try this.

```
return (
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'rgb(3,91,150)' }}>
    <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor='rgb(3,91,150)' />
    <NavigationContainer>
      <ROOTSTACK1></ROOTSTACK1>
    </NavigationContainer>
  </SafeAreaView>
);
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/status-bar